# Count to target with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for (and be as brutal as you like) ways to improve the code or the algorithm (I'm aware there should be comments) - I'm a recreational programmer and would like to be improving my skills. My next step is to get the `targetNumber` value from a nearby file without losing the current count.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Count to a particular target</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1 id="myDiv">Starting</h1> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    currentValue = 100;
    targetValue = 1500;

    function count() {
        if (currentValue > targetValue) {
        currentValue -= 1
        } else if (currentValue < targetValue) {
            currentValue += 1
        } 
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'Total wordcount:'+ currentValue.toString();
        changeTime = 20;
        if (Math.abs(currentValue - targetValue) < 980) {
            changeTime = 1000 - Math.abs(currentValue - targetValue);
        }
        setTimeout(count,changeTime/2);
    }
count()
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Whoops - did not know there was such a thing *blush*  - what's the protocal here, do I delete and repost or will it just get transfered by a passing admin?

Comment: @Joe Reddington I would just delete and repost over there. We don't have the ability to vote for this to be migrated to codereview at the moment.

Comment: If you're serious about learning better Javascript, here's a great place to start looking: http://javascript.crockford.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function count(from, to, targetElem) {
    targetElem.innerHTML = 'Total wordcount: ' + from;

    if (from == to) return;

    from < to ? from++ : from--; 

    var changeTime = Math.max(20, 1000 - Math.abs(from - to)) / 2;

    setTimeout(function() {count(from, to, target);}, changeTime);
}

count(50, 0, document.getElementById("t"));
```

A few notes:

- avoid global variables to conserve state - use function arguments instead
- *always* use `var` to declare variables. Otherwise they are in the global scope and you don't want this
- added error checking (i.e. whether values are numeric and target is valid) might not be a bad idea, I left it out for clarity here
- `return` early on known conditions, this reduces complexity in the function body
- the ternary operator `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse` can be used in other ways than assigning a value

Comment: Hmm, I'd consider `from < to ? from++ : from--;` bad style.

Comment: @RoToTa: Yes, you could say that. It's not really clean. Then again, it's crystal-clear what it does. An `if (from < to) from++ else from--;` would also be posible - I just wanted to stay on one line.

Comment: How about `from += (from < to) ? +1 : -1;` ?

Comment: @RoToRa: If you think that's clearer. ;-)