# Count to target with javascript extended

Tags: javascript

I previously asked for a review at [Count to target with JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/code-review-count-to-target-with-javascript/2680#2680), and it was a great help. I'm now looking for comments on the extended version. This code very simply counts in the direction of a particular target number, with the count slowing down as the target gets nearer.  The target number is stored in a nearby file and is often modified by other processes (so this should display a gradual change towards the new number.

Please be as brutal as you like with ways to improve the code or the algorithm (I'm aware there should be comments) - I'm a recreational programmer and would like to be improving my skills. This is absolutely my first use of AJAX and I'm amazed it worked at all :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Count to a particular target</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1 id="myDiv">Starting</h1> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    currentValue = 100;
    targetValue = 1000;//as an initialisation value
ticks=0;


    function count() {
ticks++;
if (ticks==100)
{
ticks=0;
loadtarget();
}   
        if (currentValue == targetValue) return;
        currentValue < targetValue ? currentValue++ : currentValue--;
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'Total wordcount:'+ currentValue.toString();
        setTimeout(count,Math.max(20, 1000 - Math.abs(currentValue - targetValue))/10);
 }
function loadtarget()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
   targetValue=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","target.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

loadtarget();
count()
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Count to a particular target</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1 id="myDiv">Starting</h1> 
<script type="text/javascript">

 var zCurrentValue = 100, zTargetValue = 1000, zTicks=0; // z-prefix synonym with control variables
 getHostValue(); // initial load of server data        
 intervalCheck(); 

function intervalCheck() {
  zTicks++; 

  if (zTicks==100) getHostValue(); // limit reached - get stuff
  if (zCurrentValue == zTargetValue) return; // equal - stop processing over all

  zCurrentValue < zTargetValue ? zCurrentValue++ : zCurrentValue--; // get closer to target ...
  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'Total word count:'+ zCurrentValue.toString(); // visualisation
  setTimeout(intervalCheck,Math.max(20, 1000 - Math.abs(zCurrentValue - zTargetValue))/10); // fiddle the milliseconds
}
function getHostValue() {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) ?   zTargetValue = xmlhttp.responseText : zTicks=0 ;  } // zTicks = 0 always true, at least once
xmlhttp.open("GET","target.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It can be reduced somewhat more, but the setTimeout should be reworked - so it is more clear what is going on ...